# Python crashing when launching my tkinterapp

Tags: windows, tkinter, anaconda, python-3.4

I'm experiencing this error with my other computer which I would be using for my project demonstration. It's using Anaconda 3.

Windows is giving me this error stating "pythonw.exe has stopped working". Below are the details:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   BEX
  Application Name: pythonw.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    577c1105
  Fault Module Name:    StackHash_0a9e
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000
  Exception Offset: 3f271bee
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Data:   00000008
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4
  Locale ID:    3081
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Can anyone shed light for the cause of this issue?

EDIT: I found the source of the error. It's when I pack the self._framePlotter

```
        self._framePlotter = tk.Frame(master)
        self._plotter = Plotter(self._framePlotter)
        self._framePlotter.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill = tk.BOTH, expand=True)
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you give an overview of your code? Specifically, the call to `mainloop`

Comment: Have you tried running this in the standard Python IDLE to see whether you get the same result? This could be script related or Anaconda related.

Comment: @EthanField On my laptop, it's working fine. However, it's not the case on this computer where I would test my code.

EDIT: (continuation) I've tested it on IDLE, but it's not presenting any exceptions/errors. The tk.Tk() window would show up, but then it would suddenly crash.

Comment: Are you running it in anaconda on both?

Comment: @EthanField I believe so. Because when I was testing some of my modules, it shows up with the anaconda directory.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comment section. If you need to add more information, [edit]  your question.

Comment: @BryanOakley apologies, I've made the necessary edit on my question.

Comment: What are `ybase`, `zbase`, etc? You appear to be using them before they are defined.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have initialised them on the beginning of the code, but you're correct; I wasn't able to set them as global variables on my class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/979):

Basically, uninstall the matplotlib in anaconda

```
conda uninstall matplotlib
```

Then pip install it:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Then it's fixed.